# How to solve this limit with trigonometric functions?. Should I use the Squeeze Theorem?

Tags: calculus

Given
 $$\lim_{r \rightarrow- \infty} \frac{(r^2(\cos^3(r)+\sin(r))}{((r^2+1)(r-3))}$$
Determine its value. So, I'm just wondering I could apply the Squeeze theorem because it contains $\cos$ and $\sin$. I can separate $$\lim_{r \rightarrow -\infty}\frac{1}{(r-3)}=0$$
And the remaining expression would move between $-1$ and $1$.
Suggestions will be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set $-\dfrac1x=h$ and use $$-1\le\cos x,\sin x\le1$$ for real$x$

Comment: So you get zero times some bounded value. The result is zero.

Comment: "would move between $−2$ and $2$".

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. Why do you use the substitution $-\frac{1}{x}=h$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all real values of $r$:

$$|\cos^3 r+\sin r|\le 2,$$

therefore

$$\left|\frac{r^2(\cos^3 r+\sin r)}{(r^2+1)(r-3)}\right|\le \frac{2r^2}{|r^3-3r^2+r-3|}.$$

Let $r\to\infty$, then the leading terms in the numerator and the denominator are ${2r^2}/{r^3}$. So, ${2r^2}/{r^3}=2/r\to 0$ as $r$ becomes sufficiently large.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple using asymptotic analysis

- $|\cos^3r+\sin r |$ is bounded, so $r^2(\cos^3r+\sin r)=O\bigl(r^2\bigr)$;
- A polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, so $(r^2+1)(r-3)\sim_\infty r^3$, and consequently
  $$\frac{r^2(\cos^3r+\sin r)}{(r^2+1)(r-3)}=\frac1{r^3}O\bigl(r^2\bigr)=O\Bigl(\frac1r\Bigr),$$
  and $\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac1r=0$.

Comment: Interesting.What does $O\Bigl(\frac1r\Bigr)$ mean? ,it's zero or function O?

Comment: $f(x)=O(g(x))$ (‘big O of $g(x)$’) means there exists a constant $C$ such that, for all sufficiently large $x$, one has $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|$ – in other words, the ratio $\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|}$ is bounded.

Comment: Great!.Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at these notions, as they often enable you to get rid of unnecessary computational details.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{r^2(\cos^3 r+\sin r)}{(r^2+1)(r-3)}=\frac{(\cos^3 r+\sin r)}{(r+\frac1r){(1-\frac3r)}}$$
Since$ \, 1/r\rightarrow 0$
the fraction tends to

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow- \infty} \frac{|bounded|}{r}\rightarrow 0$$